# CSS: sourced external html does not fill horizontal space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Problem

My `div` and `iframe` fill horizontal space perfectly, but if I source an HTML file then only the center portion is filled with the HTML file.  The left and right regions become a white margin.

The page HTML is like this

```html
    <div class="mainframe">
        <iframe class="helppage" src="./help_en.html"></iframe>
    </div>
```

`help_en.html` is the external HTML file.

The CSS for the div

```css
div.mainframe {
    /* fix: mainframe does not fill browser window */
    display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  height: 100%;
   /*CAUTION: must use background composite to foreground image*/
  background: url('images/bg-logo.png') no-repeat top right, #2a2f39;
  /*on-demand y-scrollbar*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  
}
iframe.helppage {
  /* fix: mainframe does not fill browser window */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
   /*CAUTION: must use background composite to foreground image*/
  background: url('images/bg-logo.png') no-repeat top right, #2a2f39;
  /*on-demand y-scrollbar*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

### Attempts

I've tried using

```css
width: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
```

But nothing changes.

### Question

How to make the HTML file display region span across the whole `mainframe` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

It turns out that the problem is that the HTML file itself has embedded style that sets its own `max-width` in its `body` like this

```css
body {

...

margin: auto;

max-width: 42em;

...
}
```

So my solution was to set it to

```css
max-width: 100%;
```